# Trying to center elements in bootstrap column for mobile screen (media queries)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Live link here http://soloveich.com/pr6/

looking at mobile screen version here http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//soloveich.com/pr6/&w=320&h=480&a=33&s=1

Been working on a couple of other issues, so, source css is a bit "dirty".

For example, logo. Here is the way I've done it.

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="side1">
<div id="side">  
<div id="logo">
<a href="<?php echo get_settings('home'); ?>"><img height="106" width="186" src="http://www.soloveich.com/pr6/wp-content/themes/accu1/images/sound-acupuncture-miami.png"></a>
</div></div></div>
```

Trying to run it with media queries

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
#side1{
width: 320px;
```

}
   }

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
#side{
width: 320px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
#logo a{
width: 186px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
}
```

It doesn't get centered. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mobile devices, below styles should put you in right direction:

```
#side {
   ... styles ...
   margin:0 auto;
}

.mainlist {
   text-align:center;
}

.mainlist ul li { float:none }
```